# How do I embed album art in an MP3 in iTunes?

Tags: windows-7, windows, itunes, mp3, id3

In each folder I have the cover art, for example:

```
/Adele
/Adele/21
/Adele/21/cover.jpg
```

`cover.jpg` is the album art. How do I embed that into my MP3s in iTunes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not a case of right clicking on the file and then choosing 'Get Info' and then clicking on the 'Artwork' tab and adding the image file? I use dbpoweramp to add images to MP3s and I've never had any issues with the artwork being in a subdirectory.